# disable mutability in a Java List

Tags: java, list, immutability

It would be nice to turn objects of Java's List interface into an immutable equivalent at the point in time that mutation is no longer required.  That is, the client can call a `freeze` method that makes the List immutable.  The immediate benefit to me is thread-safety without the memory expense of  <del>deep</del>  copying.  (**Edit**: People would be correct if they assume that one extra immutable copy, to be used by all threads, is affordable.)

Is there a third-party interface or class that provides such a feature?

Comment: Do you mean one of these? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html?is-external=true#unmodifiableList(java.util.List). You can build your own list (as a strategy), and when the freeze method is invoked, you change the internal list for an immutable list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [Collections.unmodifiableList(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)?

Answer (score 3):

There is an [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) class as part of the Guava libraries. You can use the `copyOf` method to create an `ImmutableList` from an existing `Iterable`, eg.

`List<String> immutableList = ImmutableList.copyOf(list);`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

The **CopyOnWriteArrayList** behaves much like the `ArrayList` class, except that when the list is
modified, instead of modifying the underlying array, a new array is created and the old array is discarded. This
means that when a caller gets an iterator (i.e. *copyOnWriteArrayListRef.iterator()* ), which internally
holds a reference to the underlying CopyOnWriteArrayList object’s array, which is immutable and therefore can be
used for traversal without requiring either synchronization on the list copyOnWriteArrayListRef or need to
clone() the copyOnWriteArrayListRef list before traversal (i.e. there is no risk of concurrent modification) and
also offers better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Direct using of `Collections.unmodifiableList` is not enough if the client still has a reference to the original mutable list.

I would create a delegating list implementation that would have an internal reference to the original mutable list (*the delegate*) and forward **all** of the method calls to it. It's a PITA to write such code by hand, but Eclipse for example can generate it automatically for you.

Then upon calling the `freeze` method, I would wrap the original list with the `Collections.unmodifiableList` which ensures that all of the future method calls to the `FreezingList` go to the original delegate only through the unmodifable view.

To make things more secure, but less flexible, you can change the following constructor and instead of passing the original list to it (which can still leave a reference to the original mutable list to the client) instantiate the list internally (for example as an `ArrayList`).

```
public class FreezingList<E> implements List<E> {

    // the original list you delegate to (the delegate)
    private List<E> list;

    private boolean frozen = false;

    public FreezingList(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void freeze() {
        if (!frozen) {
            list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
            frozen = true;
        }
    }

    // all the delegating methods follow:
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }
    // etc. etc.
}
```